# How to make this header and footer visible without scrolling?

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I'm writing a Web Application. I want the page to fit the browser so that the header and footer are always at the top and bottom of the browser with no scrolling needed.

I've been able to do this on the current versions of Fire Fox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer. But I can't get it to work on iPad. In landscape the iPad scales the width of the site perfect so that the full site width fits but you need to do a small amount of scrolling to see the footer. When the iPad is held in Portrait orientation I get the reverse. The full height of the site is visible with no scrolling but now you have to scroll horizontally to see the full header.

Below is a code sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/v8mkygcw/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Blank</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{margin:0;}
        #site-links {height:20px; background:#FAFAFA;  min-width:932px; border-bottom:solid 1px #A0A0A0;}
        .site-link {color:#919191; float:left; padding-right:6px; border-right:solid 1px #c7c7c7; margin-right:6px;}
        #hdr-width {max-width:1040px; min-width:640px; margin:0 auto;}

        #main{position:absolute; top:21px; bottom: 0; left:0; right:0; overflow:hidden; text-align:center;} 
        #content {position:absolute; top: 0; bottom: 21px; right:0; left:0; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:auto; }
        #footer {position:absolute; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; height:20px; background:#F8F8F8;border-top:solid 1px #A0A0A0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <div id="site-links">
            <div id="hdr-width">
                <a class="site-link">Link1</a>
                <a class="site-link">Link2</a>
                <a class="site-link">Link3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">Footer</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.site-links` has a  `min-width:932px;`

This says to the browser, no matter the size of the window, that div should have 932px at least, so the scroll appears. Remove that line from css.

http://jsfiddle.net/v8mkygcw/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sticky header and footer by giving them fixed positions:

```
#site-links {position:fixed; left:0; right:0; top:0; height:20px; z-index:1000; background:#FAFAFA;  border-bottom:solid 1px #A0A0A0;}

#footer {position:fixed; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; height:20px; z-index:1000; background:#F8F8F8;border-top:solid 1px #A0A0A0;}
```

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8mkygcw/2/) body's height was set to 1000px just for a demonstration

Answer (score 0):

Just change `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`

```css
  body{margin:0;}
        #site-links {height:20px; background:#FAFAFA;  min-width:932px; border-bottom:solid 1px #A0A0A0;}
        .site-link {color:#919191; float:left; padding-right:6px; border-right:solid 1px #c7c7c7; margin-right:6px;}
        #hdr-width {max-width:1040px; min-width:640px; margin:0 auto;}

        #main{position:fixed; top:21px; bottom: 0; left:0; right:0; overflow:hidden; text-align:center;} 
        #content {position:absolute; top: 0; bottom: 21px; right:0; left:0; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:auto; }
        #footer {position:fixed; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; height:20px; background:#F8F8F8;border-top:solid 1px #A0A0A0;}
```

```html
<div>

        <div id="site-links">
            <div id="hdr-width">
                <a class="site-link">Link1</a>
                <a class="site-link">Link2</a>
                <a class="site-link">Link3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">Footer</div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I'd be interested to try this. But I just updated my iPad to iOS 8.0 and now my original code is working correctly. I think it was a bug with mobile Safari that just got fixed.